# R callr different R version

Tags: r, system-calls, devtools, callr

Is it possible to run `callr::r` with a different R version than the one currently used? An example would be to call the following from R3.5.1, but execute it with R3.4.1.

```
callr::r(
  func = R.version.string,
  r_binary = '..../R3.4.1/bin' # inexistent argument
)
```

It should return something like "3.4.1". I have looked into `callr:::setup_r_binary_and_args`, but it takes the current R version.